# Unable to install software using brew install

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am unable to install software using `brew install`. I have tried `brew cleanup` & `brew update`, and deleting the file, but it just does not work!

This is the error message:

```
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/automake/automake-1.14.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 648f7a3cf8473ff6aa433c7721cab1c7fae8d06c
Actual: 3432ee773dd67c6333bdeda956bd364497630fab
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/automake-1.14.tar.gz
(To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.)
```

Comment: As you have already followed the advice in http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/77081 let's keep it separate from http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76733/unable-to-install-softwares-using-home-brew for the moment. What else did you try to resolve it (besides cleanup/update)?

Comment: Remove the files.  I have tried it yesterday,but the problem is still here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that gnu have moved the file so you do not get the source of automake when homebrew downloads it.

If you download the file `http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/automake/automake-1.14.tar.gz` you get

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/gnu/automake/automake-1.14.tar.gz">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at ftpmirror.gnu.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: What should the asker do to install `automake` anyway?

Comment: @patrix Homebrew need to update their brew for automaker. You might be able to change it locally or set up a local repository but I don't know enough about home-brew

Comment: It's been a while ... Did it work?